# Add a custom Price on check out page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, custom-options

I want to add radio button with some prices on checkout page when selected the price will add to grand total.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not something you can do with Magento out of the box.

There are several Extra Fee / Extra Charge extension out there, I reckon this one would fit your needs: http://magento.ikantam.com/store/extra-charge.html